# Is there a way to make unselectable a "list item" in ListView?

Tags: qt, listview, pyqt, qml, pyside

I am new to Qt. Wondering if there a possibility to make an item "unselectable" in ListView.

I see there are a lot of other things, e.g: collapsing , expanding, etc.
**
I have not find any simple example for this problem.  **

Can you provide some minimalistic examples to make a specific item in the list unselectable?

I have the following minimalistic example. How can I set list item index 2 to be unselectable?

```
Window {
   id: mainWindow
    width: 130
    height: 240
    visible: truetitle: qsTr("Hello")

    Rectangle {
        id: bg
        color: "#ffffff"
        anchors.fill: parent
    
        ListModel {
            id: nameModel
            ListElement { name: "Alice" }
            ListElement { name: "Bob" }
            ListElement { name: "Jay" }
            ListElement { name: "Kate" }
        }
        Component {
            id: nameDelegate
            Text {
                text: model.name
                font.pixelSize: 24
            }
        }
        ListView {
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: nameModel
            delegate: nameDelegate
            clip: true
    
            highlight: Rectangle {
                anchors { left: parent.left; right: parent.right }
                //height: parent.height
                color: "lightgrey"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "unselectable"? Can't make it the current item? Can't interact with it via keyboard? Mouse? Can't see it at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found numerous issues with your code snippet, so I attempted to address them all:

- I made use of `Page` and set `Page.background` instead of declaring an outer `Rectangle`. This removes a level of indentation
- I refactored `NameComponent.qml` to reduce the complexity of your main program
- I change the delegate from `Text` to `ItemDelegate` so that it is clickable, and, it being clickable, I can (1) make the ListView have active focus so that it can receive keyboard events, (2) change the current item in the ListView => I think this achieves your criteria of being able to select a different item
- I removed unnecessary anchoring from your `highlight` - your highlight will default anchor to your selected item
- I set the width of your delegate to `listView.width` - I also made use of the `ListView.view` attached property so that your delegate and access properties from the `ListView`
- Finally, I added a 20 pixel width vertical ScrollBar

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "#ffffff" }
    
    ListModel {
        id: nameModel
        ListElement { name: "Alice" }
        ListElement { name: "Bob" }
        ListElement { name: "Jay" }
        ListElement { name: "Kate" }
    }

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: nameModel
        delegate: NameDelegate { }
        clip: true
        highlight: Rectangle {
            color: "lightgrey"
        }
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            width: 20
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }
    }
}

// NameDelegate.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
ItemDelegate {
    property ListView listView: ListView.view
    width: listView.width - 20
    text: model.name
    font.pixelSize: 24
    onClicked: {
        listView.forceActiveFocus();
        if (listView.currentIndex === index) {
            listView.currentIndex = -1;
        } else {
            listView.currentIndex = index;
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: While this probably helps the OP with several problems, the actual question was about making an item "UNselectable". You added a way to select, I don't think you addressed making one unselectable.

Comment: I was hoping the OP come to the same conclusion and have him explicitly clarify "unselectable" since it is an odd requirement. Anyways, I have improved the answer by making the current item "unselected" by either clicking on a new record, or by clicking on the same record. The former, as you indicated may not be a good interpretation of "unselectable". The latter, setting `currentIndex = -1;` really removes the highlights.

Comment: Yeah, I'm surprised the OP hasn't chimed in on clarifying what "unselectable" means. I was assuming it meant that you could highlight some items in the list, but some could never be highlighted. Like having a disabled property in the ListModel or something. But they accepted your answer, so I guess they're satisfied.